# Killing Self-resurrecting Files

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, offline-files

Local computer:

- Dell desktop
- Windows XP
- Named "5"

Server:

- Windows Server 2008
- Named "W"

Whenever I delete a file, log out, and log in, the file reappears.

The files all supposedly live on the server (e.g. "\W\Home$\zchoy\Desktop") but even when the files are deleted from the server and the local computer, they come back.

I've already tried resetting the offline files cache.

I tried deleting a file and then synchronizing with the server. The file didn't come back.

However, as mentioned earlier, the file comes back once I log out and log in.

Edit:

The files are all located in \W\Home$\zchoy\Desktop and are all sorts of different types (doc, xls, exe, msi, whole folders, etc.).

Comment: Files where?  Can you give us some example names/paths?

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptions lacks some details. (Zoredache mentioned it in the comment).
Does this happen only with the user *zchoy*? or do the files also appear again and again when you log on as a differnt user? can you give us some examples of the file names?

Do you work in a domain? are there some gpo's which could lead to such behaviour?
Like a logon script which copies or creates the files on the desktop.

Are the files on the desktop really doc files and co? are the *known file types* hidden? Check it with a simple dir command (open a command prompt for it):

```
 pushd \W\Home$\zchoy\Desktop
 dir
```

Then check your autostart folder on your client (start -> programs -> autostart).
Also check the following registry keys for script or executable entries which could create the files.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Next thing I would do is upload some of the file which appear *magically* on your desktop to virscan.org or a similar website to check them for infections.

Also download and run the malicious software removal tool from microsoft
on your client and if possible on the server.
http://www.microsoft.com/security/malwareremove/default.aspx